# What's the correct time complexity of divide and conquer algorithm in searching an element in 2d and 3d array?

Tags: arrays, search, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer

a 2 dimension array nxn, sorted by low and column,

2,5,8

3,9,12

7,10,13

if I want to find whether 6 is in this matrix, use divide and conquer, first locate the central element, since 6<9, we divide the matrix into 3 matrices which are

2,5
3,9

5,8
9,12

3,9

7,10

and repeat the procedure until we find whether 6 is in or not.the recurrence relation is :

T(n)=3T(n/2)+c
time complex is O(n^1.58)

this is what we find in books and tutorials.
but some argue that since all the elements in the matrix is n^2, the real complexity should be
(n^1.58)^2=O(n^3.16)

for a 3d array, use divide and conquer

T(n)=7T(n/4)+c  complexity: O(n^1.4)

total elements in the array is n^3 so complexity is (n^1.4)^3=O(n^4.2)

Which is right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct: the runtime is `Theta(n^(log_2(3)))` or about `n ^ 1.58`.

It helps to look at what the equation actually means: T(n) is the amount of time required to find an element when the input size is n x n, i.e. a square matrix of side length n. When you recurse, the side length of the matrix in the subproblem goes from n to n/2, so `T(n) = 3 T(n/2) + O(1)`, and the master theorem bound applies.

If you prefer, let `m = n^2`, and let T'(m) be the amount of time required to find an element in a sorted square matrix with `m` total elements. Then the subproblems are 3 matrices with m/4 elements each, giving you `T'(m) = 3T'(m/4) + O(1)`. This gives you a master theorem bound of `T'(m) = Theta(m^(log_4(3)))`. After substituting `n = m^(0.5)`, you get back `T(n) = Theta(n^(log_2(3)))`.

The same logic applies for the 3D equation: you don't need to square or cube the answer afterwards arbitrarily. It also helps to note that a 2D bound of `T(n) = Theta(n ^ 3.16)` implies that the strategy is slower than reading all of the elements in the matrix, which is obviously false since we read much fewer elements.

Comment: thank you much for the explanation, pal. i got it.